# Generate octave query using java

Tags: java, readability, code-readability

I have a complicated drawing procedure written in Octave. I want to call it from JAVA. So, I am generating some octave query using JAVA to call this `draw` function. However, this part of code does not seem to me right:

```
String line = "draw('" + header + "','" + title + "'," + Arrays.toString(y1) + "," + Arrays.toString(y2) + "');";
```

Here, it is very hard to read because of the `'` and `"`s.

Is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is! Try `String.format`:

```
String line = String.format("draw('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');", header, title, Arrays.toString(y1), Arrays.toString(y2));
```